# Find out if a directory has any files in it using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a simple Bash script that needs to find out how many files are in a directory. Basically, if the directory contains no files, the script will exit. If it has any, it will do other things.

How can I find out if there are files in a directory using Bash?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about "hidden" files (i.e. files whose names start with `.`)? It almost certainly makes a difference.

Comment: Also, what if there are directories in there, but no files? `[Y/N]`

Answer (score 1):

List almost (no . or ..) all files and directories and count the lines: `ls -A1 /mydir | wc -l`

If you'd like only files I think you can use find instead: `find /mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s nullglob
cd /path/to/dir/
arr=( * )
echo "${#arr[@]}"
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "${arr[i]}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have shown you ways to get the number of files. Here is how to use the number in your script.

(This is presented in the context of a function, with `$1` being the directory name specified when you run it. To use it on the current directory, just omit that, or you can hardwire a directory name in that location.)

```
checkdir(){
    numfiles=$(ls -A "$1" | wc -l)

    if [ $numfiles -gt 0 ]
    then
       echo YES;
    else
       echo NO;
    fi
}
```

Note: this will count directories as files. If you would like *only* files, then replace the `ls...wc` portion with this line:

```
ls -AF "$1" | grep -v "/$" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing yesterday, and [found this](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html) (it's near the bottom of the page):

```
# From http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html
is_empty () (
  cd "$1"
  set -- .[!.]* ; test -f "$1" && return 1
  set -- ..?* ; test -f "$1" && return 1
  set -- * ; test -f "$1" && return 1
  return 0 )
```

It's POSIX-compatible, and uses three patterns to match any file name other than `.` and `..` which are guaranteed to exist in an otherwise empty directory.

The first two lines match all files starting with a single `.` (of length at least 2) or one or more `.` (of length at least 3), which covers all hidden files that aren't `.` or `..`. The third pattern matches all non-hidden files.

Notice that the body of the function is a `(...)` expression, not `{...}`. This forces a subshell, in which it is safe to change the working directory to simplify the patterns.

Comment: That is interesting but what are the advantages over `$(ls -A "$1" | wc -l)`

Comment: Any file whose name contains a newline (rare, yes, but possible) will show up as multiple files with `ls`.

Comment: I see. I think I have seen you (or someone) give that warning before ;^) but that is SUCH an edge case that I don't know if it is worth addressing in a day-to-day setting. Plus we are testing for zero here, so this would still work (you would get two instead of one, but you would still answer whether there is a file in the folder.) It would be informative to mention this reason in the answer, so we can learn from the subtleties. (I am not challenging you, but truly interested to know why this approach would be preferred when it seems quite complex at first glance.)

Comment: It also does everything in one process, without needing to spawn two additional processes for `ls` and `wc`.